# Are there any good examples of 'fun' interactive homepages? And are here any tutorials on creating such interactivity?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, interactive

Not too sure if this is the perfect forum for this question. Nonetheless, I want to include something interactive on my homepage. By interactive, I mean something that the user can click on or toss around or a particle emitter or something like that...

**Does anyone know of any good examples of this that I could learn from? or better yet, a tutorial on various methods?**

Thank you!

Comment: javascript /jquery will do this .... yupp ... its not perfect place

Answer (score 2):

Like @NullPointer says, **this is a Q&A site**, not a forum... and you can find a lot of resources on [Google](https://www.google.com.cu/search?q=interactive+examples+websites). However, you should check this list:

#### Examples and codes:

- *[CodePen](http://codepen.io/): Canvas animations, Javascript games and the [awesome blob effect](http://codepen.io/flash-monkey/pen/hoJbf)

#### Reading

- [Importance Of Web Interactivity: Tips And Examples](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/importance-of-web-interactivity-tips-and-examples/)

#### Websites Showcases:

- [10 Examples of Interactive Websites](http://graphicswing.com/10-examples-of-interactive-websites/)